составное именное сказуемое
Я жила в Москве
Будет ли здесь сис? Или все-таки «в Москве» будет обстоятельством?
Объясню почему я сомневаюсь. «Жил» является глаголом,который может связывать именную часть сказуемого, а «в Москве» может быть именной частью, так как это существительное с предлогом.
Но все-таки я сомневаюсь в том,что это сис.

Я жила в Москве.
Это простое глагольное сказуемое, выраженное глаголом жить. В Москве — обстоятельство места.
Почему это не СИС. Потому что нет никаких признаков именного сказуемого. СИС выражает признак подлежащего, состоит из связки и именной части.
Глагол жить может быть связкой? У Литневской он указан в списке знаменательных глаголов, но это в таком предложении: Он жил (= был) отшельником.
В Москве может быть именной частью? Это предложная форма существительного, но значения признака для подлежащего она не выражает. Сравнить: Юбка была в клетку. Все небо в тучах. Он был в восторге.
Рассмотрим вариант: Я был тогда в Москве. Но даже здесь глагол быть не является связкой, а имеет значение находиться. Это тоже простое сказуемое.
Пример СИС: Он москвич. Он был москвичом. Здесь сказуемое обозначает признак подлежащего.
КРАТКАЯ ТЕОРИЯ по учебнику Литневской, стр. 77
Сказуемое — главный член двусоставного предложения, обозначающий действие или признак того, что выражено подлежащим. Составное именное сказуемое (СИС) имеет следующую структуру:
связка + именная часть.
Связка бывает:
 1) отвлечённая: глагол быть (в значении «являться», а не 
 «находиться» или «иметься»), в настоящем времени 
 отвлечённая связка выступает в нулевой форме: Он студент / 
 был студентом.
 2) полузнаменательная (полуотвлеченная): глаголы 
 явиться(являться), бывать, оказаться (казаться),  стать и 
 т.д.   Он оказался студентом. Она казалась усталой. Можно 
 заменить на "быть".
 3) знаменательная (полнозначная): глаголы движения, 
 состояния, деятельности идти, ходить, бежать, вернуться, 
 сидеть, стоять, лежать, работать, жить и др.:

Именная часть может быть выражена однословно и неоднословно.
 1) существительное в падежной форме, чаще в И. п. / Т. п.:
 Он дворник / был дворником. Юбка была в клетку.
 2) прилагательное в полной и краткой форме, в форме любой 
 из степеней сравнения: Слова его были глупы. Он стал выше 
 отца. Он самый высокий в классе.
 3) полное или краткое причастие: Письмо не было 
 распечатано.
 4) местоимение: Этот карандаш мой!
 5) числительное: Он был восьмым в очереди.
 6) наречие: Разговор будет начистоту. Мне было жаль 
 старика.

Также добавим информацию из учебника Кустовой, стр. 72
 7) предложно-падежный оборот: Все были в восторге / в 
 страхе/в отчаянии; Все небо 0 в тучах; Вся одежда 0 в 
 грязи; Деревня под обстрелом', Провода под напряжением', 
 Письмо было от брата', Рассказ был о любви', Квартира была 
 без мебели / с балконом;
 Дом был из камня; 
 8) инфинитив: Уйти значило признать свое поражение; 
 Понимать — значит сочувствовать;
 9) нечленимое словосочетание: Он 0 хороший человек; Она 0
 девушка с характером / с голубыми глазами; Он 0 один из 
 старейших сотрудников; Камень был необычного цвета / 
 огромного размера I редкого сорта; Мы были в ужасном 
 состоянии / трудном положении I прекрасном настроении;
 1о) фразеологизм: Он 0 мастер на все руки; Он 0 стреляный
 воробей


Я находился/был в Москве - это СИС или нет?

Именная часть в СИС может быть только именительным падежом! Ну иногда творительным без предлога, точка!
Иногда бывают и все остальные падежи. В том случае, когда связка существительное с дополнением разбавляется глаголом:
Письмо из Москвы было небратским => Письмо было из Москвы
Рассказ о Москве был не любовным => Рассказ был о Москве

В нашем случае такой конструкции не получается:
Я в Москве был на квартире у брата

здесь в Москве обстоятельство, а не дополнение (и даже если бы было дополнением, то не к существительному, а к глаголу). Я в Москве явно отличается по структуре от письмо из Москвы

А у Кустовой практически все падежи указаны. Дайте ссылку на вашу информацию.

Спасибо, действительно. Рассказ был о любви, Письмо было от брата. Вообще структура типа И.п. + глагол + И.п. явно выделяется на фоне всяких там "Письмо было от брата". Я искал её отдельное название (надо еще в английском глянуть), но не нашел. Я поэтому и написал сначала только про И.п., потому что он явно выделяется.
